# URL Redirect when there is no extension available

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-6

I want to perform a redirection like this:

```
http://www.example.com/something1
http://www.example.com/something2
http://www.example.com/something3
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/something1.aspx
http://www.example.com/folder/something2.pdf
http://www.example.com/something3.aspx?id=10
```

and still show the original URL in the browser (under the hood redirect)

*The environment is IIS 6 / Asp.Net 3.5 on Windows Server 2003 SP2*

How would I do this using `web.config` or IIS.

I know how to handle redirects if I can map an extension to the `aspnet_isapi.dll` and use `Context.RewritePath(string)` but I don't know how to do that for URLs that don't have extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to move to ASP.NET 4 then there is a lot more support for extentionless URL rewriting.

However, if you have to use ASP.NET 3.5/IIS6 you can use ScottGu's blog post here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: I am aware of that and upgrading the server software is not really an option. thanks anyway.

Comment: @VaibhavGarg won't approach 2 in the link work for you? At best, you might be able to use the rewriter section of the web.config. At worst, you have to write an HttpModule to handle it via code and update the web.config to use it.

Comment: You are right, I spoke too soon. I am trying that approach and will report back after that.

Comment: unfortunately the HTTPModule doesnt get called for URLs without extensions or extensions that are not registered in IIS6.. any ideas?

Comment: creating a wildcard entry made it work. just testing to see if it works fully

Answer (score 1):

If you must stick with IIS6 and/or older .Net platform, there is an excellent tool from Helicon Tech that implements apache style .htaccess rules for the Microsoft IIS platform. They have a paid version but also a free version. The free version is limited to only processing one rules file, while the paid version can have many rules files that can be nested into a hierarchical directory structure.

I've been using the free version for a couple years and it works great. The only catch is that you must have access to the server (can't do this on a shared hosting environment unless your host already supports it).

[HeliconTech ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/)

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, it does support all major types of redirects including proxying content from one URL through to whatever presentation URL you want. [Proxy Content Example Documentation](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/examples.htm#proxy)

Comment: i dont think this will work for me as I need to determine the final URL at runtime i.e dynamic URL redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Under IIS configure a custom 404 error page e.g. `error404.aspx` which resides in your site. Within the `error404.aspx` you can access the original URL I think its `Request.RawUrl` (you may have to check that), then you can build you redirection or transfer whichever you prefer.

This may help [Accessing original URL in IIS7 404 redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070695/accessing-original-url-in-iis7-404-redirect-page)

As may this http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true