# IIS7 append "aspxerrorpath" querystring for 404

Tags: iis-7

How do I append "aspxerrorpath" querystring to custom error page on 404 in IIS7

My web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" >
  <remove statusCode="404"  subStatusCode="-1"/>
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="Redirect"  path="http://<domain>/error.aspx"  />

</httpErrors>
```

Comment: `httpErrors` are for iis 404s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing original URL in IIS7 404 redirect page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070695/accessing-original-url-in-iis7-404-redirect-page)

Comment: yes. and it works. The issue is that on IIS6 on 404s, "aspxerrorpath" querystring used to get appendind with the 404ing filename. e.g. http://<domain>/404?aspxerrorpath=%2fsfsdf.  In IIS7 it doesnt. How i get 404s behave the same way in IIS7.

Comment: iis6 won't do this for non-asp.net files.

Comment: please check my comment above.

Comment: that is part of the asp.net runtime that does that, not iis.

Comment: append the ?404; at the end of your error page can stop the iis put the aspxerrorpath parameter.