# "/" character has been replaced with the string "%2F" in error page

Tags: c#, web-config

I have error page in web config i.e;

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="/Contents/error.aspx">
        </customErrors>
```

Whenever error happens it re-direct to the error.aspx;but in error aspx if i click any button it  try to redirect as %2FContents%2Ferror.aspx.

Can anyone help me to resolve.

Comment: that is called `url Encoding`

Comment: Does using escape character ('\') help? F.e. `defaultRedirect="\/Contents\/error.aspx"`

Comment: String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8"); i cant use  because first it redirected properly.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070695/accessing-original-url-in-iis7-404-redirect-page