# log 404 urls on php and iis

Tags: php, iis, web-config, http-status-code-404

I'd like to log the URLs that are requested but returning 404.

I've a php website served by IIS7. I've this in the web.config file to redirect urls that don't exist to the 404 page:

```
 <httpErrors>
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="https://www.example.com/404.php" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

I've also:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="https://www.example.com/404.php" mode="On">
        <error redirect="https://www.example.com/404.php" statusCode="404" />
        </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Everything I can find online says I can get the original URL requested from the php variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but for me that always gives me `404.php`.

Any idea how to get the original URL requested? The way my web.config is setup appears to stop the information being passed. If I could pass the original url as a get or post variable to the 404 page I'd be able to log it that way if that's possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing original URL in IIS7 404 redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070695/accessing-original-url-in-iis7-404-redirect-page)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AmmoPT, that link was helpful.

Firstly setup web.config correctly:

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- other system.webServer stuff -->
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <!-- other system.web stuff -->
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/404.php" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error redirect="/404.php" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Note the links had to be relative to make it work for me. The above stops it actually redirecting - e.g. `example.com/idontexist.php` will show as the url but the contents of that page will be the `404.php` page

Then in the 404.php file I can detect the url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`